# draw line over my screen to indicate mouse movement

Tags: opencv, screen

I'm working with opencv and I want to do the following procedure:

Every second I check the difference between the current position of the mouse and the position it was 1 second ago.

Then I want to draw a line in my screen, from the position 1 second ago and the current position. This line should stay on the screen for 1 second until the difference is evaluated again, so the line should be renderer in the new position.

I've already done all the logics, position calculations and everything. **What I want to know is how to draw a line in my screen**. I wish to use my PC normally while I can see those lines, that means clicking with the mouse, keyboard events and opening windows should **not** stop the lines from being renderer on my screen.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't trivial.

You need *some* GUI toolkit that can show a window with the following properties:

- full-screen
- no window decoration (title bar...)
- always-on-top
- "intangible", i.e. allowing mouse and keyboard events to pass through to whatever other windows are underneath it
- a working alpha channel (per-pixel transparency)

That's the general idea. Pick a popular GUI toolkit, then google around. You'll likely find ways to do each and all of those points.

I don't think OpenCV does this. Its GUI facilities are a convenience, not flexible to this degree.